# IBM Worklight 6.0 - WebSphere Application Server -> SRVE0293E : javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-7, worklight-server

I installed a worklight **.war** on my Websphere Application server, following this tutorial : 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_dev_test_server_and_console.html

After starting my application, when I try to reach it using the following URL : `http://<ip address>:9080/<context root>/console`

I have this error in my Websphere `SystemOut.log` :

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Worklight Project not initialized]: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
```

environment config :
Windows Server 2008 R2 - Entreprise
WebSphere Application server V7
Worklight server V6
DataBase Derby (default install trough worklight server install)

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Custom authentication - custom java code doesn't seem to be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483286/ibm-worklight-6-0-custom-authentication-custom-java-code-doesnt-seem-to-be)

Answer (score 0):

The same user asked the same question also in: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Custom authentication - custom java code doesn't seem to be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483286/ibm-worklight-6-0-custom-authentication-custom-java-code-doesnt-seem-to-be)

His solution was:

> I [re] Installed a Websphere Application server 8.5 and a DB2 with the
>   worklight server V6, and now everything is working great!