# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Custom authentication - custom java code doesn't seem to be found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-7

environment config : 
Windows Server 2008 R2
Entreprise WebSphere Application server V7
Worklight server V6
DataBase Derby (default install trough worklight server install)

My Application contains in the server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml a customLogin module that use two java class located in server/java/com/authentication/

After deploying and starting my application on worklight server, when I try to reach it using the following URL : `http://ip_address:9080/context_root/console`

I have this error in my Websphere `SystemOut.log` :

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Worklight Project not initialized]: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    at     com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at     com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at     com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at     com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
```

And when I comment my custom loginModule, in authenticationConfig.xml, I don't have any problem to reach the console.

it seems that my custom authentication java classes are not defined (despite the fact that I added "server/java" folder in the Deployment Assembly of my worklight project)

Thank in advance for your time and for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you change the port to 9080? 
   Default Worklight port in Worklight 6.0 is 10080. But anyway...
2. I know that in Worklight 6.0.0.0, at least in Eclipse, to make this work you need to:

   - right-click on the project >> Properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add Library... >> Server Runtime >> Worklight Development Server >> Clean the project >> Re-build application.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Idan.
Actually I have installed my application (**.war**) on a WAS v7 where a worklight enterprise server v6 is installed (the application works well on the test environment Worklight server, port 10080, but not on the production server, port 9080 ....). 
However, when i deploy and start the sample "Custom Authenticator and Login Module" (from the "Getting started tutorial worklight v6") in my WAS everything works fine .... So i don't understand what I've missed to do (I did the step "2." before deploying and starting the **.war** on the WAS).

Comment: Exactly what is done in 2 in my answer; You need to do those changes and deploy the updated .war file that is produced.

Comment: In addition, to confirm that the custom authenticator classes have made it into your WAR file, you can open the WAR file and look into the WEB-INF/classes folder. If the .class files for your custom code are not present, then you know for a fact that the WAR file was not created properly and that you need to recreate it correctly.

Comment: @IdanAdar : I did exactly as you said ... :(

Comment: @JeremyNortey : I do have my java classes in my ***.war** on my WAS ( as follow WEB-INF/classes/com/authentication/...)

Comment: I finally solved the issue by importing a sample from the "Getting started worklight v6" page, and merged the files of my project into the sample .... I have still no clue of what was wrong ...

Comment: Actually, it didn't work at all, I Installed a Websphere Application server 8.5 and a DB2 with the worklight server V6, and now everything is working great !